# Find subspaces $U, V, \text{and} \ W$ such that $U \cap (W + V) \neq (U \cap W) + (U \cap V)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Find subspaces $U, V, \text{and} \ W$ such that $U \cap (W + V) \neq (U \cap W) + (U \cap V)$

This first part of this question was to find subspaces such that the equality holds true.
For that I used the vector space of all $M_{n,n}$ square matrices with
\begin{align}
U &= \text{All diagonal} \ n \times n \ \text{matrices}\\
V &= \text{All upper triangular}\ n \times n \ \text{matrices}\\
W &= \text{All lower triangular}\ n \times n \ \text{matrices}
\end{align}

I think I did this correctly?

But I got stuck on proving the inequality, is their some theorem or lemma that could help me in this regard? Any suggestions?

Comment: Hint: Try subspaces of $\mathbb R^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of $W$ and $V$ being the x- and y- axes of the plane. Then $W+V$ is the whole plane. What happens when $U$ is a 1-dimensional subspace of the plane that's not one of the axes?

Comment: Then $U \cap W = U \cap V = \emptyset$?

Comment: Nope: every subspace contains the zero vector. Think about it again...

Comment: Okay, so say that $U$ is a straight line through the origin, say $U = \{(x,y) : y = 2x\}$ then U is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $U \cap W = U \cap V = \underline{0}$ this would show the inequality as $U \cap (W + V) = U$ is this correct?

Comment: Yep. That's it!